# Idiomatic meaning av "Lenny's a survivor" (or similar expression)

Tags: phrase-meaning, jokes, culture

In *The Simpsons* S29E10 @ 01:33, the God's finger crashes the area of the collision and Lenny's jiggling that he's a survivor.

The character isn't connoted with particular surviving skills and I'm not familiar with any other properties specific to the series that the statement's nature might be accounted to. The statement itself seems weirdly off by its happiness, so I'm inferring a pun.

Hence, I'll expect some kind of reference and I'm assuming that it's a linguistic one. Googling for phrases akin to "*hehehe, Lenny's a survivor*" didn't lead me to anything useful.

Anybody's got an idea what that might be about?

Comment: A little bit off topic, Is the 'surviver' intentionally titled/written 'surviver'?.There is a connotation and connoted answer as well as a connotative meaning but no 'conotated' as a verb. Anyway, about this "Lenny's a survivor", where did you find it? Any Source?

Comment: Might very well be wrong, but the idea could be that it's not in reference to anything.  God smashes everything. Lenny pops right back up, and declares "Lenny's a survivor!"  lol.  In reference to nothing.  That is the joke. (the absurdity and cheerfulness.)

Comment: It just mean someone who survives a [biblical] catastrophe, the obvious epitome of which would be [Holocaust survivor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%27erit_ha-Pletah). Jews who survived the Nazi death camps are sometimes called, simply, "survivors."

Comment: @Flonne That was two typos - thanks and sorry. As for where it comes from, well, the title of the series is *The Simpsons*, 29th season's 10th episode, about 93 seconds in. Not subs or such, so it's my side floppies that are responsible for hearing (possibly incorrectly).

Comment: The to be a survivor is a cliché in American culture: survivor of a disaster, abuse, crime,accident etc. You can google any of those and read the psychological "interpretations" of this topic. [questions in English: [has anybody got any idea or do you have any idea or does anybody have any idea//anybody's is not use at the beginning of sentences like that]

Comment: @Robusto That's actually a really good swing. However, it'd make more sense if they picked [one of the Jewish characters](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Jewish_Characters) and not [Lenny who likely isn't](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Lenny_Leonard). However, It's said that his ancestors were in Soviet prison (and Jews have been oppressed in Stalin Russia). He's also a member of the equivalent of Stonemasons that are sometimes accused to be a Jewish conspiracy ruling the world... So you might be more right that I originally realized.

Comment: @Sam That **could** be the case but knowing the depth of the series, I find it more likely that I'm too uneducated to catch the point than that they just made an absurd joke with no layers of sophistication.

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular reference to anything. Lenny has just survived a crash (and the finger of God).  The contrast of the bad situation and the cheerful comment is the joke.

The scene is a parody of "La La Land" a musical about Hollywood.

Comment: Ah, I see. Didn't realized that the scene itself was a reference to anything. I haven't seen *La La Land* yet.